# How to set logout automatically using session in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, session

I am working on asp.net project. I need know how to logout automatically after 5 mins using session concept or other methods.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

I agree to the comment, but I try to give you some advices.

You have different possibilties to set the timeout.

For example:

1. Using the web.config. In the web.config file you may define the timeout for the user's session (check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx for more info)
2. Using .NET. This is specific. If you are using cookies (not sessions), check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178194%28v=vs.100%29.aspx for more information about a cookie expiration definition.

I hope I could lead you to a helpful way.

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="5"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Specify the sessionState timeout property in your web.config file. This means that the session will expire in 5 min after being left idle.

Every page that requires user authentication must call a common function which checks if the session is still active. If the function determines that the session has expired it should redirect the user to a page that shows a session expired message and prompts the user to re-login.